# drop-down list and action bar on honeycomb

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm working on Android 3.0, and I would like to add a drop-down list in the action bar. This drop-down list will have to display a list of "missions" of the day. So I'm not sure that this tutorial is useful for me : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown

As a beginner I'm a bit lost.
If you have any clue...

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to get the example code working from the link that you included in your question and then tried to adapt it to your requirements?

Comment: The example uses Fragment. And I can't use Fragment system in my project because I've a MapView and support for MapFragment is...inexistant ? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15347

Comment: There is a link in comment 5 of the thread that you posted which details precisely how to implement a MapFragment.

Comment: Yes, but I have to use the original compatibility pack. That's why I tried to avoid that "hack". But now i feel a bit stuck because the only documentation on {drop-down list/spinner} inside an actionbar uses the Fragment system that I can't realy use in my case.

Comment: Why do you have to use the original compatibility pack? That doesn't support ActionBar.

Comment: Because I'm an intern. And because my bosses are stupid, and that I've many constraints.

Comment: In that case there's little option for you but to look at the sample code and try to remove the Fragment dependencies. It's not hard, and will give you a much better understanding of what's actually going on.

Comment: Seems pretty hard to me. Otherwise I would not have asked my first question.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a resource to get people to write your code for you. If you have specific problems, then people will help you, but this is simply to broad a question to ask if you're not prepared to actually try things yourself.

Comment: I wasn't asking people to write code for me. I just wanted to know a way to realize the thing without fragment system.